# Average of noisy samples

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, mean

I am not a statistician so I hope my question is not trivial. I have a set of $n$ samples affected by Gaussian noise with mean 0. I need to estimate the average of the samples, without the noise. Is there a better estimation then the sample mean itself?

I was hoping that the noise would cancel itself in the mean since it has mean 0, but it does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that no, an average is the best you can do. There is no way to completely eliminate noise, only reduce it.

The more technical answer is that the maximum likelihood estimator for the average of normally distributed data is a simple average, so you can't do any better than that. If the noise in each individual sample has a standard deviation of $u$ then the noise in the sample average will have a standard deviation of $\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}$. So as your number of samples $n$ gets larger, the amount of noise in the average gets closer and closer to 0.